Which of these options would be an acceptable way of writing A = 12 cm^2 in LaTeX? Select all that apply
Which of these options would be an acceptable way of writing A = 12 cm^2 in LaTeX? Select all that apply.
$A = 12\text{ cm}^2$
\(A = 12 cm^2\)
\(A = \mathrm{12, cm^2}\)
\(A = 12\text{ cm}^2\)
\(A = 12\mathrm{ cm^2}\)
\(A = 12\text{ cm^2}\)

Why are you asking the exact same question as in the question that is linked as duplicate.
